# Adding different images based on if post is liked

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm creating a social media website, where users can like each others post. I have successfully done most of this.

I have allowed a user to like and dislike posts, and displayed a list of the users who have liked the post in my template.

One issue I have is changing an image based on whether the user has liked the post or not.

My current implementation is incorrect, and I am unsure how to solve it. Currently, I have a variable on the Post model(is_liked), and an image changes depending if this is true or not.

My problem with this is if one user likes a post, it shows up as liked for every user.

I want it so everyone can't see the graphic that is displayed when a post is liked, and only if they like it themselves.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    is_liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py:

```
def likepost(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tuser = request.user
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)

        if post.likes.filter(id=tuser.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(tuser)
            post.is_liked = False
            post.save()
        else:
            post.likes.add(tuser)
            post.is_liked = True
            post.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

home.html(template)

```
    {% if post.is_liked == True %}
      <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like__post{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 115px; left: 34px;"> <img src="{% static 'redheart.png' %}" width="22px"  height="22px"> </div></a>
   {% else %}
      <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like__post{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 115px; left: 34px;"> <img src="{% static 'heart.png' %}" width="22px"  height="22px"> </div></a>
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: By adding an image, do you mean have an image pop-up on the screen?

Comment: No I mean displaying it in a regular <img> tag.

Comment: In the home.html template, within the <a> tag, you can see an <img> tag that is shown whether a post is liked or not.